# How to solve SSL certificate verify failed when installing composer?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on Windows, but i get the following error:

```
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: 
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I am currently on my company's laptop, so i'm restricted in playing with firewall and so on.

I have tried to download a ca file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and updated my `php.ini`  as follows:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo =C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem

[openssl]
openssl.cafile=C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem

extension_dir = "ext"

extension=curl
extension=openssl
```

I also have openssl when i run `php -m`

When I run `php -i` i get the following options under `openssl` :

```
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1q 5 Jul 2022
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1q 5 Jul 2022
Openssl default config => C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL/openssl.cnf
```

However, I notice the path for `Openssl default config` is wrong with the `/` and `\` and also I cannot find the `SSL` folder inside `Common Files`.